# $\int_0^\pi \tan(\theta + \text{i}a)\text{d}\theta$ =?

Tags: complex-analysis

Solve the integration
$$\int_0^\pi \tan(\theta + \text{i}a)\text{d}\theta$$
Where $a\in \mathbb R$ and $a \neq 0$

The method I took is to let $$z=e^{i\theta}$$ and since $$\tan(\theta+ia)=\frac{\sin(\theta+ia)}{\cos(\theta+ia)}=\frac{\sin\theta\cos ia+\sin ia\cos \theta}{\cos\theta\cos ia-\sin\theta\sin ia}$$
So we can do a complex substitution.

However, I got something like: $$\int_{C}\frac{(cha+sha)z^2+sha-cha}{iz((cha-sha)z^2+cha+sha)}dz$$

And its singularity is awkward to me.

Where am I wrong? Or is there a better solution?

Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:**

Separating into real and imaginary components,

$$\tan{\left(\theta+ia\right)}=\frac{\sin{(2\theta)}}{\cos{(2\theta)}+\cosh{(2a)}}+i\frac{\sinh{(2a)}}{\cos{(2\theta)}+\cosh{(2a)}}.$$

Then, integrating over $0\le\theta\le\pi$ we see that the real part of the integral vanishes:

$$\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{\pi}\tan{\left(\theta+ia\right)}\,\mathrm{d}\theta
&=\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{\sin{(2\theta)}}{\cos{(2\theta)}+\cosh{(2a)}}\,\mathrm{d}\theta+i\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{\sinh{(2a)}}{\cos{(2\theta)}+\cosh{(2a)}}\,\mathrm{d}\theta\\
&=-\frac12\int_{1}^{1}\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{u+\cosh{(2a)}}+i\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{\sinh{(2a)}}{\cos{(2\theta)}+\cosh{(2a)}}\,\mathrm{d}\theta\\
&=i\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{\sinh{(2a)}}{\cos{(2\theta)}+\cosh{(2a)}}\,\mathrm{d}\theta.
\end{align}$$

The imaginary integral can be evaluated using the tangent-half-angle substitution.

Comment: This is meaningful. However, what about trying to use Residue's Theorem to avoid the integral effort? Thank you.

Comment: @ZhenZhang I never really learned residue theory so I can't say whether that would be easier. Sorry :/

Answer (score 1):

\begin{equation}
\tan(\theta+ia)=\frac{\sin(\theta+ia)}{\cos(\theta+ia)}=\frac{\frac{e^{i(\theta+ia)}-e^{-i(\theta+ia)}}{2i}}{\frac{e^{i(\theta+ia)}+e^{-i(\theta+ia)}}{2}}=\frac{1}{i}\frac{e^{2i(\theta+ia)}-1}{e^{2i(\theta+ia)}+1}
\end{equation}

Substitute $e^{2i(\theta+ia)}$ with $z$, $\mathrm{d}z=2ie^{2i(\theta+ia)}\mathrm{d}\theta$, then it becomes a circle with radius $\vert z\vert=e^{-2a}$.

The integral becomes
\begin{equation}
I=\frac{1}{i}\int_{\vert z\vert=e^{-2a}}\frac{z-1}{z+1}\frac{\mathrm{d}z}{2iz}=-\frac{1}{2}\int_{\vert z\vert=e^{-2a}}\frac{z-1}{z(z+1)}\mathrm{d}z
\end{equation}

When $a>0$, $0<e^{-2a}<1$, the pole of $f(z)=\frac{z-1}{z(z+1)}$ inside the circle is only $z=0$. The residue is $-1$, hence the integral is $\pi i$. When $a<0$, $e^{-2a}>1$, the pole inside the circle is $z=0,-1$. The sum of two residues is $1$, hence the integral is $-\pi i$.

To summarize it, $I=\text{sgn}(a)\pi i$.